# Transaction with request scope with MyBatis and Spring

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

Is there a way to setup MyBatis with SpringMVC to have one transaction for whole http request? Generally is there something like Hibernate `OpenSessionInViewFilter` in MyBatis or should I write my own filter to fulfill such behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confused by notions "session" and "transaction". OSIV opens session, in one session several transactions may coexist. Usually you should put `@Transactional` attributes to services which are used by controllers, depending on your business requirements.

Moreover, one big transaction for everything is an anti-pattern. Ideally is to have a read-write transaction for a user's actions, and then another read-only transaction is to build a response for the user. It saves resources, because database locks taken for inserts/updates are released earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You may let Spring take care of your transactions.

Take a look on the documentation. I is quite easy.
You just need to configure and add the @Transactional annotation in methods that requires it.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

Comment: Yes it is true. But my question is if there is possibility to have transaction for whole request with MyBatis like `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter` with Hibernate that binds a session to the thread for the entire processing of the request. E.g. you don't have to add @Transactional annotation at all.

Comment: You may create a Spring managed servlet filter and you annotate the doFilter method with @Transactional.

Comment: Sure that's my answer if there is a MyBatis made solution for this or if I should write my own filter... I don't want reinvent wheel if I don't have to ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you do really need to have a single transaction bound to a particular request, you may consider to use `TransactionTemplate` within your `Filter`. I don't think you can use `@Transactional` on `Filter` unless if it is managed by Spring (e.g: part of `FilterChain` like Spring Security's Filters.

Here is what you can do with `TransactionTemplate`

```
public class TransactionalFilter implements Filter {
    private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest req, final ServletResponse resp, final FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
                try {
                    chain.doFilter(req, resp);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ServletException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(config.getServletContext()).getBean(PlatformTransactionManager.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to re-throw the exception instead of just printing a stack trace, otherwise the transaction won't be rolled back on exception. Otherwise a perfect idea!

Answer (score 0):

My advice is reading up on the following help document:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/transaction.html

Since you don't have full control of each part of the spring-mvc framework I suggest using an aop pointcut on a base class of spring-mvc to start the transaction (a method that is executed on each request.)  You can find this approach in section 10.5.2.
Just make sure that the class you pointcut is initialized by spring otherwize it will not work.